# Is a binary search really better than my solution? (Google Kickstart 2020 Round B)

Tags: python, binary-search

So the question I am referring to is :-

> Bucket is planning to make a very long journey across the countryside by bus. Her journey consists of N bus routes, numbered from 1 to N in the order she must take them. The buses themselves are very fast, but do not run often. The i-th bus route only runs every Xi days.
>
> More specifically, she can only take the i-th bus on day Xi, 2Xi, 3Xi and so on. Since the buses are very fast, she can take multiple buses on the same day.
>
> Bucket must finish her journey by day D, but she would like to start the journey as late as possible. What is the latest day she could take the first bus, and still finish her journey by day D?

So, after the round finished, I looked up for POV of other programmers, and almost most of them used a binary search to solve this question, however, my solution was really basic.

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
  no_of_buses, no_of_days = list(map(int, input().split()))
  list_of_timing = list(map(int, input().split()))
  temp_test_day=0
  check_no = no_of_days
  ans=[]

  for i in list_of_timing[::-1]:
    div = int(check_no/i)
    ans.append(i*div)
    check_no=(i*div)
  print("Case #"+str(_+1)+": "+str(ans[-1]))
```

So, I basically just found out the highest(compared to the bus to take after it) multiple of the interval of days the buses ran on, and got the answer.
Sorry, if my explanation was bad, I am a total newbie (a month or two in) in programming, so I turned to you guys for help.
Can someone explain if my solution was better or worse than a binary search?

(PS- If it helps, my code was accepted for both the test sets)

Thank you.

OG Question- https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/000000000019ffc8/00000000002d83bf

Comment: Your answer is the same idea I would have used (although I would have used `%` or `//` instead of `int(x/y)*y` - less rounding error), and it's the alternate solution given on the analysis page. The binary search approach is slower and more complex, and just seems kind of silly to me.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks a lot! And yes, using "//" would have been better but the time limit had me on my nerves, so I just forgot about it.

Comment: With Small edits it works and all test cases passes