# Google Kickstart round B 2020

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to programming but today I tried to solve a problem in Google Kickstart 2020 round B " Bus Routes":
https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/000000000019ffc8/00000000002d83bf

My program worked well with the sample cases, but when it came down to the test sets, it ran into Runtime Error. I really don't know why this happened and I will really appreciate if someone can help me to point out my mistakes. Here are my codes:

```
t = int(input())
tc = 0
def check_valid(day, bus_route, index, max_day):
    if index >= len(bus_route):
        return True
    if day % bus_route[index] == 0 and day <= max_day:
        return all([check_valid(day, bus_route, index + 1, max_day)])
    elif (day + 1) % bus_route[index] == 0 and (day+1) <= max_day:
        return all([check_valid(day + 1, bus_route, index + 1, max_day)])
    return False
while t > 0:
    bus_route_number, max_day = map(int, input().split())
    route = list(map(int, input().split()))
    latest = 0
    if all([max_day % i == 0 for i in route]):
        latest = max_day
    else:
        for day in range(max_day, 0 , -1):
            if check_valid(day, route, 0, max_day):
                latest = day
                break
    tc += 1
    print("Case #" + str(tc) +":", str(latest))
    t -= 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Questions here must be self-contained; please copy the relevant information from the challenge, your expected results, the exact error message or test failure message, etc. directly into your question with an [edit].

Comment: I have not digged into your code or the challenge but one possible thing is that there are resource limits placed on these challenges (time it takes to process, amount of memory your program consumes etc.). If you are running the program in their environment, you might be breaching some of these due to inefficiency of your algorithm. This may result in the runtime error.

Comment: Python is somewhat inefficient when it comes to memory usage & runtime. For these kind of problems I suggest using not script languages. I agree with @MatusDubrava, I also think that is the problem!

Comment: @nagyl, these kinds of challenges are rarely constrained by languages. Any performance that needs to be achieved can usually be done by finding the right _algorithm_. A bad algorithm implemented in C is just as bad as the same algorithm implemented in Python.

Comment: @Chris Ik, just saying. I usually do my code in C when it comes to performance & memory usage, especially if it involves big data (in the challenge you have 10^12 routes max). Python is as good as C for this challenge, you are right, but I like to have more control over memory usage, or achieve slightly better performance. Take a look at any coding challenge site, the best result is going to be written in C.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61420575/is-a-binary-search-really-better-than-my-solution-google-kickstart-2020-round **With small addition**